# Can I make a formula 'follow' a cell after sorting?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an Excel file with a number of different sheets to keep track of grades for a class I'm teaching. The first sheet is a list of students' names, as well as their overall scores for each assignment, their overall score for the course, and a VLOOKUP table to show letter grades. This sheet is called `Overall`. There are also a number of other sheets to keep track of running scores for various assignments.

One of those sheets is used to sort the students in to groups for group work, and enter their scores for the group work. I am using a formula in the `Overall` sheet to call the score for the group work from a sheet labelled `Presentation`.

The `Overall` sheet is sorted alphabetically by students' last name. When I sort the students by last name in the `Presentation` sheet, the formula works, and the score I put in for the first student in the list on the `Presentation` page goes to the top of the list `Overall` page.

When I sort the students so I have the groups stacked in order, and then students in order by last name within their groups, the formula on the `Overall` sheet still calls the same cell. For example, the student who is at the 'top' of the list sorted by group number, and then by last name in the `Presentation` sheet, is actually in the third position in the `Overall` sheet.

So on the `Overall` sheet, the formula to grade the group work score for that student is `=IF($A6="","",Presentation!C5)`, but when the `Presentation` sheet is sorted as described above, that student's score for the group work is no longer in `Presentation!C5`. Instead, it's in `Presentation!C3`, which puts that score into the top position.

My question is: Is there a way to make a formula 'follow' a cell when it's been sorted?

Apologies for any lack of clarity in the explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the C5 come from? Are the two sheets setup so that the same record has an equivalent piece of data on the other sheet in the same relative position?

Comment: I made a mistake when I explained it the first time.

Comment: Could you use a VLOOKUP to get the info from presentation?

Comment: Sorry, my first post contained an error.

The sheets are initially set up as you describe.

I want to keep the `Overall` sheet sorted alphabetically by last name. The formula for the call to the `Presentation` sheet is `=IF($A6="","",Presentation!C6)`. That calls C6 in the `Presentation` sheet. My issue is that the relative position will change as I sort `Presentation` by group.

I want to automate the process of changing the formula on the `Overall` sheet to `=IF($A6="","",Presentation!**C3**)`, when the `Presentation` sheet is sorted by group by using something like `Fill Down`.

Comment: I think VLOOKUP is how I'll have to do it. I'm not too comfortable with VLOOKUP, but I'll play around with it.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me that VLOOKUP was the way to go. I ended up with the following VLOOKUP statement:  `=VLOOKUP(A4 & B4,Presentation!$A$4:$D$47,4,0)`  This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJ1MO2xx8wQ) explains how to use VLOOKUP across different sheets.  I used a range of `lookup_value`s so I can still sort both lists by first and last name independently. To make this work, I used a '[helper column](https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-multiple-critiera)'.  Thanks again.

Comment: You should paste this below as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reassuring me that VLOOKUP was the way to go. I ended up with the following VLOOKUP statement: =VLOOKUP(A4 & B4,Presentation!$A$4:$D$47,4,0) This video explains how to use VLOOKUP across different sheets. I used a range of lookup_values so I can still sort both lists by first and last name independently. To make this work, I used a 'helper column'.